# WCF WebHttp, Service, Behaviors, Endpoints, Custom Formatter

Tags: wcf, service, endpoint, behavior, webhttp

I followed this guide for creating my custom formatter so I could use the Newtonsoft Json.NET for object serialization since the built in Microsoft one doesn't support cycles from parent/child relationships.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/03/wcf-extensibility-message-formatters.aspx

In his example he's manually creating his ServiceHost.  I am leveraging Routes and the WebServiceFactory taught to me by this guide.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/06/introducing-wcf-webhttp-services-in-net-4.aspx

From what I can tell I just need to figure out a way to add the appropriate Behaviour to my Service endpoints.  Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Some code snippets below for ease of reference...

---

In my Global.asax

```
        WebServiceHostFactory webServiceHostFactory = new WebServiceHostFactory();
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute(Accounts.Route, webServiceHostFactory, typeof(Accounts)));
```

---

If my web.config

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
<standardEndpoints>
    <webHttpEndpoint>
    <!-- 
        Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint 
        via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
    -->
    <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
    </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```

---

In the Main function of his program

```
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITestService), new BasicHttpBinding(), "soap");
        WebHttpBinding webBinding = new WebHttpBinding();
        webBinding.ContentTypeMapper = new MyRawMapper();
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITestService), webBinding, "json").Behaviors.Add(new NewtonsoftJsonBehavior());
```

Comment: If you're looking to support REST, I would definitely recommend adopting the new WCF WebApi framework if your designing a SOA based on REST. The extensibility points in the new bit found at wcf.codeplex.com are great and easy to work with. Aside from a few kinks the WCF team is working out, Preview 4 has been excellent to work with. For JSON.NET support check out my post here: http://wcf.codeplex.com/discussions/255870

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the routes and get a reference to the service endpoint, you'll need your custom service host factory. It can do the same as the WebServiceHostFactory which you're currently using (simply return a reference to the WebServiceHost), but instead return a reference to your custom service host.

You can find more information about service host factories at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/14/wcf-extensibility-servicehostfactory.aspx.

```
public class MyServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        return base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
    }

    class MyServiceHost : WebServiceHost
    {
        public MyServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
            : base(serviceType, baseAddresses)
        { }

        protected override void OnOpening()
        {
            base.OnOpening();

            foreach (ServiceEndpoint endpoint in this.Description.Endpoints)
            {
                CustomBinding custom = endpoint.Binding as CustomBinding;
                if (custom != null)
                {
                    custom = new CustomBinding(endpoint.Binding);
                }

                custom.Elements.Find<WebMessageEncodingBindingElement>().ContentTypeMapper = new MyRawMapper();
                endpoint.Binding = custom;

                endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new NewtonsoftJsonBehavior());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome I'll give it a try later today!  Thanks for the feedback Carlos!

Comment: is it possible to define attribute in configuration file instead of writing code.....I noticed configurable attribute for wsBasicHttpEndpoint but not for webHttpEndpoint